# WebAPI protected resource for adding/editing/deleting scenarios

Tags: c#, .net, authentication, asp.net-web-api, owin

I have the following setup `WebAPI` hosted on IIS with `OWIN token authentication`with the following scenario:

- users have a personal resource like, let's say profile that only they can edit;
- in my application I identify users by a randomly generated `ID`;
- I keep this `ID` in the front-end and the requests to the `API` contain it

Now I want to ensure and `authorize` a request to edit the personal resource such that only the owner (e.g. the user whose profile is) can modify any field.

After the request to modify  this resource arrives, I want to check that the caller(taken from the request) is the same as the one from `HttpContext` (so that is someone modifies the publicly available id in his request to be denied the edit command).

Remember that in my request I keep the `ID` of the user, while on `HttpContext.Current.User.Identity` contains the email. At this point I can make a call to the user manager and search the database for the user with the email from `HTTPContext` and check if the IDs are equal. But this requires me to question the database even before I start actually executing the command (so from the performance point of view is not perfect).

Is there a way I can populate `HttpContext` with the `ID` (among with the email or change  the `Name` property from `User.Identity` to `ID`) so I can have something like `HttpContext.User.Identity.Id` (since I think I can't modify that object - obvious reasons)? Or `HttpContext.User.Identity.Name` to give me the `ID`.

Or is it ok at all to use `HttpContext` inside `WebAPI`?

Thanks,
Radu

EDIT: After looking around the Locals during an `API` call, I have come across several places from where I can retrieve the Identity:

1. `ActionContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name`
2. `ActionContext.ControllerContext.Principal.Identity.Name`
3. `ControllerContext.RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name`
4. `RequestContext.Principal.Identity.Name`
5. `User.Identity.Name`

While  I feel that the last one (so: `User.Identity.Name`) could be the one I can use regardless of the application type (so I can call from a web browser, desktop application, mobile application), I am not quite sure.

Also, is there any way I can populate the `Identity` with my ID?

Thanks!

Comment: WebAPI and `HttpContext`. There's some design smell there!

Comment: Ok, so what is the appropiate way of retrieving the `Context` of a request? Thanks!